# should develop wordpress plugin with MVC pattern

Tags: wordpress

I am senior PHP developer but I am beginner of wordpress. I am going to write a plugin for wordpress, I want it is easy to other wordpress developer in the world can customize it, that is most important point. So should I do the plugin with MVC pattern?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.io) as your starting point for creating plugins. It's not MVC, but it is a good example for how WordPress plugins should be put together.

Comment: @Kirk Beard Great plugin, every beginer should know it

Answer (score 2):

It is not compulsory to write wordpress plugins in MVC , the best way to write wordpress plugin is in OOPS ( Function Base).
Normally, plugin developer prefers oops structure . 
I will suggest you to quickly go through [this plugin development guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) development guide will help you in deep and you have much experience in php so it is easy for you to understand it very quickly.

I wish this may help you, thanks.

Comment: Thank for your answer but what I am talking about is that I afraid that other wordpress developer will hard to change my plugin because I saw some famous plugins like woocommerce, they do not use MVC

Comment: Sorry for my miss understanding ,It is not compulsory to write into MVC mostly plugins are in OOPS (Function base) . and by using hooks you will allow other developer to change or overwrite the plugin functions. so that is most important. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I want!